# How to check if number_id is in a.myid?

Tags: django

This is my model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    number = models.FloatField(..)
    myid = models.IntegerField()
class B(models.MOdel):
    name = models.CharField(..)
    number_id = models.IntegerField()
```

queryset:

```
a = A.objects.all()
```

my try:

```
b = B.objects.filter(number_id__in=a.myid)
```

How to check if `number_id` is in `a.myid`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a foreign key to show this type of relationship:

```
class A(models.Model):
    number = models.FloatField(..)
    myid = models.IntegerField()
class B(models.MOdel):
    name = models.CharField(..)
    number = models.ForeignKey('A')
```

...and then the checking will be done automatically at the DB level; it will be impossible to add a relationship other than to 'A' class.

Answer (score 0):

```
B.objects.filter(number_id__in=A.objects.all().value_list('id', flat=True))
```